# How to read an Array from Arduino via I2C and Java

Tags: java

I want to read an Array from Arduino and I am confused about how to do that. In my code below I am receiving just the first number of the integers {1,2,3,4}. I read many examples but I don't understand them because I am new to Java programming. So if there is someone who can help me to fix that ai will be very grateful. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.pi4j.io.i2c.I2CBus;
import com.pi4j.io.i2c.I2CDevice;
import com.pi4j.io.i2c.I2CFactory;
public class I2C_Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
                System.out.println("Creating I2C bus");
                I2CBus bus = I2CFactory.getInstance(I2CBus.BUS_1);

                System.out.println("Create I2C device 1");
                I2CDevice device = bus.getDevice(0x8);
                    int []f =new int[5];

                    for( int i = 0 ; i < f.length ; i++ )
                    {
                       f[i]=device.read();
                        }
                  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(f));
                  } catch (IOException ex) {
              ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

Here is the "Slave" code - Arduino:

```
#include <Wire.h>
#define SLAVE_ADDRESS 0x5 // Slave board with adress 0x5
#define SIZE 5

void setup() {
  // initialize i2c as slave
  Wire.begin(SLAVE_ADDRESS);

  // define callbacks for i2c communication
  Wire.onRequest(sendData);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
}

void sendData() {
byte buf[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
Wire.write (buf, sizeof (buf));
}
```

Comment: Whaat's wrong with your code? You send 1,2,3,4 and you receive 1,2,3,4. Isn't that the expected behaviour?

Comment: Hi! 
No, I am receiving just 1. I tried with char and string but the result was the same. I am using Raspberry Pi 3 as master and Arduino as a slave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue I see is that you read a single character at `f[i]=device.read();` when you really ought to grab the entire array in a single read.